# Collision Problem

Tags: java, awt, paint, collision

I'm having a problem with checking the colision of objects painted on the screen. For example: I'm currently making a snake game and I have to make it check whether the snake is hitting a certain block object ( which makes the snake increase and increases the score when the snake hits/'eats' the block ). So I made a function to check the collision between the snake and the block object but it doesn't work correctly ( when moving over the object with the snake from right above, it does work, but otherwise it does not ):

```
public boolean checkColision() {
    if(SnakeObjs.get(0).x >= obj.x && SnakeObjs.get(0).x
                <= obj.x+10 && SnakeObjs.get(0).y
                >= obj.y && SnakeObjs.get(0).y <= obj.y+10) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function checks the collision. Where `SnakeObjs.get(0)` contains the x and y choords of the snake object that needs to hit the block object and the `obj` contains the x and y coordinates of the block object to check the collision with.

The paint method, painting both the block object and the snake object, looks like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for(int i=0;i<SnakeObjs.size();i++) {
        g.setColor(new Color(
                        (int)((double)Math.random()*200.0),
                        (int)((double)Math.random()*200.0),
                        (int)((double)Math.random()*200.0)));
        g.fillRect(SnakeObjs.get(i).x, SnakeObjs.get(i).y, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(SnakeObjs.get(i).x-1, SnakeObjs.get(i).y-1, 12, 12);
    }
    g.setColor(new Color(
                    (int)((double)Math.random()*200.0),
                    (int)((double)Math.random()*200.0),
                    (int)((double)Math.random()*200.0)));
    g.fillRect(obj.x, obj.y, 10, 10);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("Score: "+score, 10, 10);
}
```

If anyone can help me out on this collision problem it would be great.

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: a snake game is *the* typical kind of game where you represent your objects and walls using a grid.  For example an int[][] array where, say, a '0' means 'nothing', a 'Integer.MAX_VALUE' means wall, a '1' means that the snake can eat the 1 and grow by one, a '2' means the snake the '2' and grow by two, etc.  Your *checkCollision* hence becomes *if ( grid[x][y] == Integer.MAX_VALUE )* etc.

Comment: Ahh I see, but I did use rectangles instead of just points for both the snake object and the block object, so would that make it some more complex? Also I think I will get it to work now by checking the intersection between rectangles instead. But thanks for also showing the way using a grid anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is that you interpret one object as rectangle and the other as point. You check if the point is in the rectangle and not if the both rectangle intersect. That it work from right and from top.

I recommended to save an rectangle for the snake and the object. Ad a method getBounds(). then you can use the method intersect() from Rectangle. You can also use this bounds for your draw operation.

Comment: Ahh I totally got it! Thanks a lot, I now see where I went wrong in my redenation on checking the collision. So I basicly need to check whether, not just one point ( probbably was the left top point which was used as it starts drawing the rectangle from right top position right? And so that point had to lay within the range of the block object so had to hit it from the right,top) but the bounds of the snake object rectangle (either of them) lay within the block object rectangle if I get it correctly now. I will try to get it work now using the bounds of both rectangles instead, thanks!